# Storing private messages in a database

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key-management, databases

I am creating a portal where users can send **private messages** (PMs) for a **very large audience**. So I want to encrypt the messages and store them in the database. But I do not want to ask the users for new keys. So here's what I have planned:

A randomly generated **symmetric key** will be allocated to every pair of users, which will be stored in the database using their **passwords** in an **asymmetric scheme**. Using this symmetric key, I intend to encrypt all their messages. So, even if either of them changes their password, I won't have to encrypt all the messages using the new pair of keys. Also Alice and Bob will **not** be notified of their shared symmetric keys.

This solves my problem of changing passwords and users do not have to set new keys. But is this an overkill? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That means when you have n users, you will have n² public keys in the database. That's quadratic growth. When you have a million users, a million of keys will have to be generated when a new user registers. This might not scale too well.

Comment: What's the attack vector you want to protect against anyway?

Comment: If you're handling all the encryption, you don't even need a key-per-user, you can just encrypt it with a single key.  Since otherwise you'd have to control access to the decryption keys, you can simply control access to the message - encrypting the database would be just to prevent disclosure if the db gets stolen.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I am developing it for someone else. So they will have access to the database as well as the source and the server. That's why I am considering this method.

Comment: @Philipp In this system, messages can be sent only to friends. So I will already have to keep track of all the pair of users who can communicate, so having a key-pair for all them doesn't seem like that bad an idea.

Comment: er, what?  How does that change anything?  Beyond being a potentially problematic requirement from a client, I mean.  So far, nothing you've described about your system would warrant that kind of effort.  At most, if it was **required** to store the messages encrypted per-user, I'd just assign everybody public/private keys, then encrypt per-destination-user.  But you'd have to store the _keys_ securely anyhow, which would best be accomplished by encrypting them with an application key, at which point why not just encrypt the db with the application key...

Comment: But I would have to store the application key in a config file, which would be accessible by the client. I don't want the client to be able to read the messages of the users of his service.

Comment: @batman when you want to secure private messages, there is no reason not to use public/private keypairs where the public key of every user is available to anyone.